# Statement timeout error in postgreSQL for large data

Tags: postgresql

We have recently migrated to PostgreSQL 15 from Oracle.
My table structure is as in image below. Only indices are primary keys.

[image: table structure]

We have this program for finding duplicate( for an entity if any staging record exists in main, then mark as duplicate in staging detail)
Main table has approx. 500 million of data. The below query works when staging table has approx. 1 million records (1 million ~ 500 million comparison), but gives statement timeout error for more than 1 million records. No new index was created in PostgreSQL. Do we have option to increase memory or timeout time in Postgres or any new index can be created to run this query for large data?

**Edit** : edited query with unique_id >= 15684 condition

```
    SELECT FD.file_id, FD.LINE_NO
from staging_header FH 
left join staging_detail FD on FH.file_id = FD.file_id
left join(main_header H left join main_detail D
on H.unique_id = D.unique_id)
ON (FD.TXN_DATE = D.transaction_date and FD.MID = D.merchant_id and FD.TID = D.terminal_id and FD.TXN_REF_NO = D.tx_ref_no
where FH.entity_id = 'XXXX' and FH.entity_id = H.entity_id and unique_id >= 15684
and FH.PROCESS_FLAG = 'N' and FH.PROCESS_STATUS = '00'
and FD.PROCESS_FLAG = 'N' and FD.PROCESS_STATUS = '00'
```

We have approx. 76 month wise partitions for main_detail table on **transaction_date** column.

Output of EXPLAIN ANALYSE:

```
Gather  (cost=686297.66..56604907.59 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=391652.590..397957.305 rows=0 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=685297.66..56603907.49 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=391629.181..391630.151 rows=0
loops=3)
         Hash Cond: ((d.transaction_date = fd.txn_date) AND ((d.merchant_id)::text = (fd.mid)::text) AND ((d.termina
l_id)::text = (fd.tid)::text) AND ((d.tx_ref_no)::text = (fd.txn_ref_no)::text) AND ((d.auth_code)::text = (fd.auth_
code)::text))
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=748.33..53211966.04 rows=61120806 width=74) (actual time=48280.346..300238.985 rows=14
2758659 loops=3)
               Hash Cond: (d.unique_id = h.unique_id)
               ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..51719090.37 rows=568323296 width=77) (actual time=0.242..248105.291
rows=454658663 loops=3)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202204 d_68  (cost=0.00..2765248.17 rows=31161217
width=79) (actual time=0.131..36385.007 rows=74786917 loops=1)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202205 d_69  (cost=0.00..2570672.60 rows=28713160
width=83) (actual time=0.139..34076.709 rows=68911584 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202210 d_74  (cost=0.00..2525110.23 rows=27849423
width=88) (actual time=0.066..34458.420 rows=66838615 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202208 d_72  (cost=0.00..2437750.12 rows=27017712
width=85) (actual time=1.309..31526.598 rows=64842508 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202209 d_73  (cost=0.00..2417680.45 rows=26714745
width=88) (actual time=0.389..30640.660 rows=64115389 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202207 d_71  (cost=0.00..2380965.98 rows=26395098
width=85) (actual time=1.878..30367.172 rows=63348237 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202206 d_70  (cost=0.00..2288957.10 rows=25457710
width=84) (actual time=1.225..30613.453 rows=61098506 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202203 d_67  (cost=0.00..2228805.72 rows=27047072
width=79) (actual time=1.204..30554.095 rows=64912973 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202211 d_75  (cost=0.00..2114584.45 rows=23342545
width=89) (actual time=2.361..28424.133 rows=56022109 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202110 d_62  (cost=0.00..1929836.90 rows=23170790
width=79) (actual time=1.908..24234.816 rows=55609894 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202112 d_64  (cost=0.00..1916823.43 rows=23095743
width=80) (actual time=0.309..24250.450 rows=55429782 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202202 d_66  (cost=0.00..1841871.05 rows=22302905
width=81) (actual time=0.920..23430.150 rows=53526972 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202111 d_63  (cost=0.00..1811233.87 rows=21760687
width=80) (actual time=1.175..10110.061 rows=17408550 loops=3)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202201 d_65  (cost=0.00..1781216.65 rows=21494365
width=81) (actual time=1.924..14664.887 rows=25793238 loops=2)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202108 d_60  (cost=0.00..1672640.07 rows=19995007
width=78) (actual time=1.034..21265.332 rows=47988018 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202109 d_61  (cost=0.00..1642747.75 rows=19685775
width=78) (actual time=0.495..20735.015 rows=47245860 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202107 d_59  (cost=0.00..1582179.23 rows=18876623
width=75) (actual time=1.217..24656.746 rows=45303895 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202106 d_58  (cost=0.00..1416963.00 rows=16879900
width=75) (actual time=0.461..18096.119 rows=40511759 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202104 d_56  (cost=0.00..1247189.85 rows=14815785
width=73) (actual time=1.271..16250.747 rows=35557883 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202105 d_57  (cost=0.00..1034296.03 rows=12273802
width=75) (actual time=0.279..12897.524 rows=29457126 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202001 d_41  (cost=0.00..660224.22 rows=7901322 wi
dth=62) (actual time=0.851..8385.719 rows=18963171 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202103 d_55  (cost=0.00..636403.65 rows=7600365 wi
dth=59) (actual time=0.636..7917.474 rows=18240877 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201912 d_40  (cost=0.00..634131.68 rows=7575968 wi
dth=62) (actual time=0.981..7876.041 rows=18182322 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202002 d_42  (cost=0.00..618985.88 rows=7403088 wi
dth=61) (actual time=0.443..7823.615 rows=17767413 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202101 d_53  (cost=0.00..594448.23 rows=7099623 wi
dth=60) (actual time=0.579..7617.154 rows=17039096 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202012 d_52  (cost=0.00..592949.22 rows=7075422 wi
dth=60) (actual time=0.289..7599.207 rows=16981011 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202102 d_54  (cost=0.00..557941.45 rows=6666945 wi
dth=59) (actual time=1.097..8469.829 rows=16000668 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202011 d_51  (cost=0.00..551561.22 rows=6580722 wi
dth=60) (actual time=2.323..7845.248 rows=15793732 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202010 d_50  (cost=0.00..541516.32 rows=6465732 wi
dth=60) (actual time=3.071..7509.806 rows=15517757 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202003 d_43  (cost=0.00..500525.41 rows=5982441 wi
dth=61) (actual time=0.505..6566.428 rows=14357859 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202009 d_49  (cost=0.00..498229.27 rows=5952427 wi
dth=60) (actual time=1.340..6354.120 rows=14285824 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202008 d_48  (cost=0.00..473451.19 rows=5649219 wi
dth=60) (actual time=1.899..6152.809 rows=13558126 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202007 d_47  (cost=0.00..442856.52 rows=5280052 wi
dth=60) (actual time=0.688..5718.016 rows=12672124 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202006 d_46  (cost=0.00..431238.51 rows=5139651 wi
dth=60) (actual time=1.022..5570.241 rows=12335163 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202005 d_45  (cost=0.00..322049.82 rows=3843882 wi
dth=59) (actual time=0.514..4179.456 rows=9225317 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202004 d_44  (cost=0.00..170375.59 rows=2033059 wi
dth=59) (actual time=1.270..2200.745 rows=4879342 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201911 d_39  (cost=0.00..99748.34 rows=1126534 wid
th=60) (actual time=0.442..1238.540 rows=2703682 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201904 d_32  (cost=0.00..77520.76 rows=877776 widt
h=60) (actual time=1.233..1038.713 rows=2106663 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201905 d_33  (cost=0.00..75244.24 rows=852324 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.033..1018.941 rows=2045578 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201908 d_36  (cost=0.00..71581.46 rows=807346 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.034..756.542 rows=1937631 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201907 d_35  (cost=0.00..70736.10 rows=798410 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.031..815.549 rows=1916185 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201906 d_34  (cost=0.00..70287.73 rows=795673 widt
h=60) (actual time=4.525..1071.337 rows=1909616 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201910 d_38  (cost=0.00..64894.83 rows=731183 widt
h=60) (actual time=4.229..1106.733 rows=1754839 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201909 d_37  (cost=0.00..64030.31 rows=722131 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.036..1115.049 rows=1733114 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202212 d_76  (cost=0.00..62668.10 rows=734710 widt
h=70) (actual time=0.502..941.721 rows=1763305 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201704 d_8  (cost=0.00..20424.27 rows=244827 width
=59) (actual time=0.023..253.853 rows=587584 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201805 d_21  (cost=0.00..18971.21 rows=222421 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.365..255.920 rows=534441 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201806 d_22  (cost=0.00..17918.28 rows=211428 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.022..244.113 rows=507427 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201804 d_20  (cost=0.00..17845.21 rows=210521 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.033..227.176 rows=505301 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201803 d_19  (cost=0.00..17609.88 rows=208088 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.018..201.712 rows=499411 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201810 d_26  (cost=0.00..17272.90 rows=203890 widt
h=60) (actual time=3.561..241.027 rows=489337 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201811 d_27  (cost=0.00..16898.90 rows=199690 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.016..226.327 rows=479255 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201801 d_17  (cost=0.00..16872.47 rows=199347 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.011..228.096 rows=478432 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201809 d_25  (cost=0.00..16693.76 rows=197076 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.011..232.691 rows=472983 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201808 d_24  (cost=0.00..16615.35 rows=196135 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.527..256.811 rows=470725 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201705 d_9  (cost=0.00..16518.85 rows=196985 width
=60) (actual time=0.633..247.533 rows=472764 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201710 d_14  (cost=0.00..16385.53 rows=192653 widt
h=61) (actual time=0.011..242.029 rows=462368 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201807 d_23  (cost=0.00..16300.88 rows=192788 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.011..212.557 rows=462691 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201712 d_16  (cost=0.00..15956.17 rows=189018 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.377..233.791 rows=453642 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201903 d_31  (cost=0.00..15630.37 rows=184637 widt
h=60) (actual time=2.076..195.545 rows=443129 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201802 d_18  (cost=0.00..15556.97 rows=183697 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.019..200.397 rows=440872 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201812 d_28  (cost=0.00..15281.62 rows=180662 widt
h=60) (actual time=2.067..209.129 rows=433590 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201709 d_13  (cost=0.00..14963.41 rows=177641 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.011..207.096 rows=426339 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201901 d_29  (cost=0.00..14355.48 rows=169448 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.453..200.458 rows=406674 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201708 d_12  (cost=0.00..14190.58 rows=168458 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.676..187.462 rows=404299 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201711 d_15  (cost=0.00..13645.50 rows=161350 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.487..190.109 rows=387239 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201902 d_30  (cost=0.00..13521.67 rows=159367 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.643..183.340 rows=382480 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201706 d_10  (cost=0.00..13430.53 rows=159553 widt
h=60) (actual time=0.981..186.323 rows=382928 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201707 d_11  (cost=0.00..13163.89 rows=156389 widt
h=60) (actual time=2.020..183.935 rows=375334 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201703 d_7  (cost=0.00..926.89 rows=14989 width=60
) (actual time=0.009..10.364 rows=25481 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201612 d_4  (cost=0.00..14.23 rows=223 width=61) (
actual time=0.009..0.556 rows=379 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201610 d_2  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408) (
actual time=0.000..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202301 d_77  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202302 d_78  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202303 d_79  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202304 d_80  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202305 d_81  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202306 d_82  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202307 d_83  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202308 d_84  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202309 d_85  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202310 d_86  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_202312 d_87  (cost=0.00..10.29 rows=29 width=408)
(actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201702 d_6  (cost=0.00..7.06 rows=106 width=61) (a
ctual time=0.009..0.457 rows=180 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_before_2016 d_1  (cost=0.00..2.43 rows=43 width=21
6) (actual time=0.010..0.027 rows=73 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201701 d_5  (cost=0.00..2.35 rows=35 width=60) (ac
tual time=0.318..0.336 rows=59 loops=1)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_detail_201611 d_3  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=408) (ac
tual time=0.453..0.458 rows=4 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=717.83..717.83 rows=2440 width=13) (actual time=100.803..100.806 rows=4086 loops=3)
                     Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 212kB
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on main_header h  (cost=47.54..717.83 rows=2440 width=13) (actual
time=1.429..99.670 rows=4086 loops=3)
                           Recheck Cond: ((entity_id)::text = 'W002'::text)
                           Filter: (unique_id >= 15684)
                           Heap Blocks: exact=421
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_pos_cb_hdr_t99  (cost=0.00..46.93 rows=4086 width=0) (actual
time=1.002..1.002 rows=4086 loops=3)
                                 Index Cond: ((entity_id)::text = 'W002'::text)
         ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=661416.16..661416.16 rows=606763 width=101) (actual time=7268.024..7268.037 rows=1
894307 loops=3)
               Buckets: 65536 (originally 65536)  Batches: 128 (originally 32)  Memory Usage: 7136kB
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.85..661416.16 rows=606763 width=101) (actual time=3559.203..5547.343 rows=1894
307 loops=3)
                     Hash Cond: (fd.file_id = fh.file_id)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on staging_detail fd  (cost=0.00..642716.64 rows=6977776
width=96) (actual time=1.887..4871.854 rows=5580857 loops=3)
                           Filter: (((process_flag)::text = 'N'::text) AND ((process_status)::text = '00'::text))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 162
                     ->  Hash  (cost=7.62..7.62 rows=18 width=13) (actual time=0.154..0.157 rows=46 loops=3)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on staging_header fh  (cost=0.00..7.62 rows=18 width=13) (ac
tual time=0.082..0.126 rows=46 loops=3)
                                 Filter: (((entity_id)::text = 'W002'::text) AND ((process_flag)::text = 'N'::text)
AND ((process_status)::text = '00'::text))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 121
Planning Time: 65.403 ms
Execution Time: 397960.649 ms
(117 rows)
```

Comment: Please don't use measurements which are not globally understood -- *Cr*, *L*  etc.

Comment: That JOIN syntax looks really strange. I didn't know that `left join (main_header h left join ...)` was even valid. Also: all outer joins are turned back into inner joins due to the WHERE clause.

Comment: As you don't need columns from the staging tables, I would try to rewrite this as an EXISTS condition `select ... from main_detail where exists (....)`

Comment: Could you share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, COSTS) for your SQL statement? Otherwise nobody knows what the query plan looks like. I also have no idea what L or Cr is.

Comment: Sorry for the abbreviations. Cr - Crore (10 million), L - Lakh (0.1 million)

Comment: @BKElizabeth And please don't use those in your question. Those are not globally used or understood.

Comment: I have removed those measurements and added the query plan also in the question.

Comment: You don't have any useful index, see all the sequential scans. The planner also expects half a billion records, that will never be fast. Did you run ANALYZE to collect statistics?

Comment: I have replaced EXPLAIN output with that of EXPLAIN ANALYSE

Comment: The tables main_header and main_detail are not used in the output nor the WHERE conditions. Why did you put them in the query? (or did I miss something?)

Comment: We are checking for duplicates using join condition between staging detail (FD ) and main detail (D) - FD.TXN_DATE = D.transaction_date and FD.MID = D.merchant_id and FD.TID = D.terminal_id and FD.TXN_REF_NO = D.tx_ref_no. The output records need to be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Your execution plan contains extra newlines. Please fix that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you please mention which extra lines you are referring to? There are some parallel scan on partitions of main_detail table. Are you referring to those? I have corrected the query with unique_id filter also.

Comment: There are line breaks in the formatted text you posted.